# Is it possible to make a chat using only php and the windows cmd?

Tags: php, windows, cmd

I have a school project where I need to make a chat (client/server-side) using only PHP and cmd to debug (No WebSockets allowed), and the teacher who as given us this project it's not very familiar with PHP.

Saying that, me and my partner have already spent looking some hours looking for something like this but everything that we see it's using WebSockets or it's with client sides not synchronized with the server.

Do You guys know if this is even possible to do?

Comment: the easiest way of "communication": a text file on a shared network folder.

Comment: Oh there is something called Server sent events you might want to look into:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: @MagoPT happy to see you joining Stack Overflow MagoPT! Asking questions on SP is easy but you have to ask yourself before posting one: 1. Is this question broad enough? (your case: yes) 2. Is it narrow enough? (your case: no) 3. Does it show what research I have already done? (your case: no).
I think you should look for `polling` techniques. Perhaps SockJS on github.
After playing with SockJS, if you're stuck and had a more specific question do come back here and ask your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP is a server language, a live chat system wouldn't really be possible using only PHP as the page would have to refresh for every new comment in order for both parties to be able to see it so it would be a very clunky and unreliable system.

Languages required for a live chat system:
PHP & JAVASCRIPT
Libraries required for a live chat system:
JQUERY & AJAX (AJAX is built into JQUERY)

The following tutorial may be of interest.
https://www.webslesson.info/2018/07/live-chat-system-in-php-using-ajax-jquery.html

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down, to avoid getting voted down again I need to know why, please explain. Thanks.

Comment: see [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)